# How can I calculate the normal and inverse normal distribution function in SAS?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I need to calculate the normal and inverse normal distribution of two columns in my dataset in SAS Enterprise Guide.

The dataset is something as follows:

```
Prob    St.Dev  
0.82    -1.46   
0.29    -0.02   
0.01    -1.00   
0.32     0.92
```

I need to calculate the cumulative standard normal distribution function for the standard deviation column and the inverse cumulative standard normal distribution function for the prob column.

The output should be as follows:

```
Prob    St.Dev  Normdist   Norminv
0.82    -1.46     0.072     0.915
0.29    -0.02     0.492    -0.558
0.01    -1.00     0.159    -2.453
0.32     0.92     0.824    -0.460
```

By looking online I only found the function PROBNORM(x), however I do not know the full syntax needed (From PROC; to QUIT;) to implement the function correctly.  
Thank you in advance

Comment: A normal distribution is parameterized with its mean and standard deviation. I'm not sure which you need for the inverse normal. You can use PROC UNIVARIATE with HISTOGRAM to find the parameters and see the curves or you can calculate them manually using PROC MEANs. It's not clear what you want as output either. What would you like to see from that data?

Comment: I added the expected results calculated using the excel "Normsdist" and "Normsinv" functions for each row of data. Also, it was mentioned that the calculation needs to be done on a standard normal function, which implies a mean of zero and a sigma of 1.

Comment: Isn't that just the CDF function then? I don't see an inverse normal but normal is there. https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=n1rnj32uvtwnvfn1kwnsg9d6w6h7.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want the CDF() & QUANTILE() function.
Assuming you have a data set called `have` with a variable called `prob`, your full solution would look like:

```
    *make fake data to test;
    data have;
    input Prob    St_Dev  ;
    cards;
    0.82    -1.46   
    0.29    -0.02   
    0.01    -1.00   
    0.32     0.92   
    ;;;


    data want;
    set have;
    *calculate new variables;
    normdist = cdf('normal', st_dev);
    norminv = quantile('normal', prob);

    run;

    *print for display;
    proc print data=want;
    run;
```

Comment: Yes I do need the CDF, but could you please clarify what I should put after PROC to make this function work? The inverse normal does the opposite of the normal i.e. if the normal CDF takes a standard deviation as an input and gives me the probability then the inverse takes the probability and gives me the standard deviation.

Comment: That would be a probnorm then. This is code for a data step not a PROC.